# Django ImageField default

Tags: python, django, django-models, imagefield, django-imagekit

**models.py:**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_upload_file_name,
                              storage = OverwriteStorage(),
                              default = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT,'images','generic_profile_photo.jpg'),
                              height_field = 'photo_height',
                              width_field = 'photo_width')
    photo_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
    photo_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
```

**views.py:**

```
def EditProfile(request):

    register_generator()
    source_file = UserProfile.objects.get(user = request.user).photo

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args.update({'source_file' : source_file})
```

somewhere in my **template**:

```
{% generateimage 'user_profile:thumbnail' source=source_file %}
```

I receive an error: 
UserProfile matching query does not exist.

at this line:

```
source_file = UserProfile.objects.get(user = request.user).photo
```

The problem is that the default atribute of ImageField is not working. Thus, the object is not created inside my model. How to use this atribute properly? If I ommit this atribute, the object is created with no errors. Do I need to pass the absolute or relative path?
I am using django-imagekit to resize the image before dispalying it: http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 15):

If you don't define the default attribute, does image uploading work successfully? When I implemented an ImageField in my own django project, I didn't use the default attribute. Instead I wrote this method to get the path to the default image:

```
def image_url(self):
"""
Returns the URL of the image associated with this Object.
If an image hasn't been uploaded yet, it returns a stock image

:returns: str -- the image url

"""
    if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
        return self.image.url
    else:
        return '/static/images/sample.jpg'
```

Then in the template, display the image with:

```
<img src="{{ MyObject.image_url }}" alt="MyObject's Image">
```

EDIT: Simple example

In views.py

```
def ExampleView(request):
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user = request.user)
    return render(request, 'ExampleTemplate.html', { 'MyObject' : profile } )
```

Then in the template, include the code

```
<img src="{{ MyObject.image_url }}" alt="MyObject's Image">
```

would display the image.

Also for the error 'UserProfile matching query does not exist.' I assumee you have defined a foreign key relationship to the User model somewhere in your UserProfile model, correct?

Comment: Yes that's true for your las question. I will try your solution. It is working fine if don't add the default attribute

Comment: The relevent view: http://pastebin.com/bfwrwgSB and form: http://pastebin.com/3vSH4Sjw. I used class-based views

Comment: actually, I was curious how do you call the image_url() method. Or how to you create and send the MyObject object to the template

Comment: check my edit. I would also suggest doing all the image resizing and other processing you need before saving it, if possible

Comment: this is a great idea

Comment: 3 years later! Awesome answer!